# Layer-backed NSView performance with rendering directly in CALayer.drawInContext:

Tags: cocoa, calayer, nsview, nsscrollview

I have many layer-backed views contained in a `NSScrollview` and am *predominantly concerned with scrolling performance*. The `documentView` and higher are layer-backed hence their subviews are also layer-backed.

The following are the three natural places that display/rendering code could go:

1. override `NSView.wantsUpdateLayer` to return false (or don't do anything because this is the default) & do drawing in NSView's `drawRect` method
2. override `NSView.wantsUpdateLayer` to return true & do drawing in NSView's `updateLayer` method
3. do NO drawing in `NSView` at all & perform all drawing in CALayer's `drawInContext` method

From the *WWDC 2013 Session 215* talk it was stated that (2) is more performant than (1) because the view then doesn't need to create a temporary store for the drawRect output. Firstly, I don't have 100% clarity on when "backing stores" are made and when not and Secondly how do (2) and (3) compare and when might you use one over the other?

In particular, I have to draw text into my view. **How would I go about doing that in the updateLayer call?** The only examples of drawing text seem to need to get hold of a context - which isn't naturally available in `updateLayer`.