# Layer backed NSView with custom CALayer not calling updateLayer?

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, calayer, nsview, appkit

I have a custom layer-backed NSView and have overidden the makeBackingLayer method to return a custom CALayer subclass. I have also overriden wantsUpdateLayer to return true thereby fully opting into layer-like drawing.

```
override func makeBackingLayer() -> CALayer {
    return Layer() // my custom class with "drawLayer:" implemented
}

override var wantsUpdateLayer:Bool{
    return true
}

// never called
override func updateLayer() {
    super.updateLayer()
    println("updateLayer after")
    self.layer?.borderWidth += 1
}
```

Once I do this, I find that when I set `NSView.needsDisplay = true` it routes calls to the custom layer's drawInContext: method as opposed to the updateLayer: method. **Why does it do this?** In my example, I have checked that if I remove the `makeBackingLayer` override then my `updateLayer` is called in the expected manner.

I can't quite put my finger on it, but other instances point to the notion that when your makeBackingLayer`returns a custom`CALayer` that you actually have your custom layer hosted inside a parent backing layer. (Pure Speculation on my part)

Further, would there be different performance characteristics between the two drawing routes given that CALayer's drawInContext: is more "low-level"? See this SO question for more detail on that question: [Layer-backed NSView performance with rendering directly in CALayer.drawInContext:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109137/layer-backed-nsview-performance-with-rendering-directly-in-calayer-drawincontext)

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Surely you fixed it by now, but for future readers I found a possible explanation by reading the  [NSView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSView/wantsUpdateLayer)!

> If the `canDrawSubviewsIntoLayer` property is set to YES, the view
>   ignores the value returned by this method. Instead, the view always
>   uses its `drawRect:` method to draw its content.

Answer (score 2):

Did you forget to set the `layerContentsRedrawPolicy` and `wantsLayer` properties?

```
self.wantsLayer = YES;
self.layerContentsRedrawPolicy = NSViewLayerContentsRedrawPolicy.OnSetNeedsDisplay;
```

Comment: I have the property precisely as you have it above. Unfortunately that is not the answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you override `makeBackingLayer`, it becomes your responsibility to set up that layer, including setting its `delegate: CALayerDelegate`. It's enough to set the `delegate` to the view using that layer. From there, you can implement any of those delegate methods, though you probably want `func display(_ layer: CALayer)`. See [Core Animation Guide - Providing a Layer's Contents](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/SettingUpLayerObjects/SettingUpLayerObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH13-SW4) for more on this.

The code path for `updateLayer` depends on the `NSView` using the default layer type. Here is my working `NSView` subclass that redraws on bounds change:

```
/**
 A view backed by a CAShapeLayer that can inscribe an image inside the
 shape layer's circular path
 */  
@IBDesignable final class InscribedImageView: NSView, CALayerDelegate {

    @IBInspectable private var image: NSImage?
    @IBInspectable private var color: NSColor = .clear

    // swiftlint:disable:next force_cast
    private var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer { return self.layer as! CAShapeLayer }

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        configureViewSetting()
    }

    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: decoder)
        configureViewSetting()
    }

    private func configureViewSetting() {
        wantsLayer = true
    }

    override func makeBackingLayer() -> CALayer {
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.delegate = self
        layer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = true
        return layer
    }

    func display(_ layer: CALayer) {
        inscribe(image, in: color)
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        inscribe(image, in: color)
    }

    func inscribe(_ image: NSImage?, in color: NSColor) {
        self.color = color
        defineCircle(color: color)
        subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
        if let image = image {
            self.image = image
            let imageView = NSImageView(image: image)
            imageView.imageScaling = .scaleProportionallyUpOrDown
            imageView.frame = bounds
            addSubview(imageView)
        }
    }

    private func defineCircle(color: NSColor) {
        shapeLayer.path = CGPath(ellipseIn: shapeLayer.bounds, transform: nil)
        shapeLayer.fillColor = color.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = color.cgColor
    }
}
```

Note that I didn't need to set `wantsUpdateLayer` to return true on my subclass OR the subclass's `layerContentsRedrawPolicy = LayerContentsRedrawPolicy.duringViewResize`. Presumably this is because both rely on the stock layer type, not a subclass.

Here are some more useful resources from my previous, incorrect answer:

[Apple's Core Animation Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/SettingUpLayerObjects/SettingUpLayerObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH13-SW8)

> Overriding wantsUpdateLayer and returning YES causes the NSView class to follow an alternate rendering path. Instead of calling drawRect:, the view calls your updateLayer method, the implementation of which must assign a bitmap directly to the layer’s contents property. This is the one scenario where AppKit expects you to set the contents of a view’s layer object directly.

Also in **NSView.h**, the docs for `updateLayer` are

> /* Layer Backed Views: If the view responds YES to wantsUpdateLayer, then updateLayer will be called as opposed to drawRect:. This method should be used for better performance; it is faster to directly set the layer.contents with a shared image and inform it how to stretch with the layer.contentsCenter property instead of drawing into a context with drawRect:. In general, one should also set the layerContentsRedrawPolicy to an appropriate value in the init method (frequently NSViewLayerContentsRedrawOnSetNeedsDisplay is desired). To signal a refresh of the layer contents, one will then call [view setNeedsDisplay:YES], and -updateLayer will be lazily called when the layer needs its contents. One should not alter geometry or add/remove subviews (or layers) during this method. To add subviews (or layers) use -layout. -layout will still be called even if autolayout is not enabled, and wantsUpdateLayer returns YES.
>    */